# How to put two different metrics in a table panel

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am designing a dashboard for kafka using Grafana and prometheus. I have 2 different metrics i.e. count of leader replicas on a host, count of total replicas on a host.
I can create two different tables in grafana i.e.

```
Total leader replicas
Host | #leader replicas
A | 10
B | 20

Total replicas
Host | #replicas
A | 50
B | 100
```

If I try to show metrics together then it creates a table as following:

```
Host| leader replicas | follower replicas
A| 10 | -
B| 20 | -
A| - |50
B| - |100
```

Is it possible to merge above tables and show something like following in Prometheus?

```
Host | #leader replicas | #replicas
A | 10 | 50
B | 20 | 100
```

Answer (score 0):

In Grafana, the name of the metric appears in the `__name__` label. This causes a mismatch in the matching of rows in the table.

The only solution I have found so far is to add a computation that doesn't transform the data.

Making up the name of you metrics, the requests would be

```
A. sum(replica_number) by (host)
B. sum(leader_number) by (host)
```

The values will then be align on the row of the host.